# Div and transition to transparency

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a problem with the site:

http://mbprojects.designy.pl/projekty/galaktikafilm/slider/demo.php

I do not know how to make the transition on both sides of the div with slider to transparency in css(?).

Like here:

http://s24.postimg.org/vbvn9pzzp/Screen_shot_2013_03_22_at_15_20_58.jpg

I'll be grateful for a hint.

Comment: That's probably just a PNG with partial transparency overlaying the content.

Comment: You could also do it with CSS gradients, though IE will give you fits.

Comment: Wow! What is a java slider? I've never heard of one!

Comment: http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking under header "Linear Gradient Masks" could be worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess and the easiest solution would be to put a Div/img over top of your slider that has full transparency in the center but completely opaque at either edge.

Hope this helps.